# CentOS 7: sshfs can't find fuse, even though fuse is loaded

Tags: centos7, vps, sshfs, fuse, modprobe

When I try to run sshfs, I get the error `fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first`. I already ran `sudo modprobe fuse`, but it just returns immediately without any output and the error persists:

```
[root@localhost main]# modprobe fuse
[root@localhost main]# sshfs user:password@my.server.com mnt
fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
```

I can also verify that fuse is loaded:

```
[main@localhost ~]$ lsmod | grep fuse
fuse                    4242  -2
```

This is on a VPS with freshly installed CentOS. The OS is up-to-date, as far as I can tell:

```
[main@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
```

Running virt-what yields the following:

```
[root@localhost ~]$ virt-what
openvz
lxc
```

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Comment: Also at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459039/centos-7-sshfs-cant-find-fuse-even-though-fuse-is-loaded

Comment: Use count is -2? That's broken. Reboot the system.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Wow, you're right... I didn't even notice that. Just rebooted the system but its still -2. Not only for fuse, but for every entry generated by ```lsmod```. Btw I didn't install CentOS myself - I'm using a pre-configured image from my server provider.

Comment: @MichaelHampton According to this answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269734/302687) the ```-2``` means that ```CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD``` is set. Could it be that ```sshfs``` is confused by the ```-2```? What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eww, it's OpenVZ. That's why it doesn't work. You can't load modules (properly) on OpenVZ without the VPS provider doing it for you. These guys somehow managed to screw it up. Go find a nice KVM VPS.